# Object is not a function error when trying to instantiate model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

I am trying to instantiate a model in a backbone.js router which I have included through require.js. However, I keep getting the following error;

`Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function`

Here is the model;

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'], function($, _, Backbone) {
    var AppState = Backbone.View.extend({});
    return AppState;
});
```

And here is the router where I am trying the instantiate the model.

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'models/appstate'], 
function($, _, Backbone, AppState) {

    var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
          '': 'index'
        },

        index: function() {
            var appState = new AppState();
        }
    });
    return new Router();
});
```

The model file is being included and all paths are correct.

Comment: You may want your model to extend model and not view for starters : )

Comment: Yep, that was it. Can't believe I didn't see it... Rookie error :/ Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have your model extend model instead of view.